# js fade in onLoad with for-loop, styles, and setInterval not working?

Tags: javascript, animation, opacity, fadein, setinterval

Why when calling fadeIn() onLoad does the browser run through the loop immediately. In other words there is an issue with either the setInterval or the Opacityto().

```
function Opacityto(elem,v){
    elem.style.opacity = v/100;
    elem.style.MozOpacity =  v/100;
    elem.style.KhtmlOpacity =  v/100;
    elem.style.filter=" alpha(opacity ="+v+")";}

function fadeIn(){
elem=document.getElementById('nav');
for (i=0;i==100;i++){
    setInterval(Opacityto(elem,i),100);}
}
```

I think someone will tell me this can be done easiest with jQuery but I'm interested in doing it with javascript.

Thanks!HelP!

Comment: Why not look at the JQuery source on github and see how they do it?

Comment: Eval is evil, bro. Pass real functions to setInterval instead of strings.

Comment: @missingno IT WORKED once, when I first took the quotes out. but then stopped working for every subsequent reload. I think you got me a little closer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several problems with your `fadeIn()` function:

A. Your for loop condition is `i==100`, which is not true on the first iteration and thus the body of the for loop will never be executed (the `i++` won't ever happen). Perhaps you meant `i<=100` or `i<100` (depending on whether you want the loop to run 101 or 100 times)?

B. Your `setInterval` code has a syntax error **EDIT:** since you've updated your question to remove the quotes - `setInterval` expects either a string or a function reference/expression. So you need to either pass it the name of a function *without* parentheses and parameters, or a function expression like the anonymous function expression you can see in my code down below. <s>in the way you try to build the string you are passing it. You've got this:</s>

```
"Opacityto("+elem,i+")"
```

but you need this:

```
"Opacityto(elem," + i + ")"
```

The latter produces a string that, depending on `i`, looks like `"Opacityto(elem,0)"`, i.e., it produces a valid piece of JavaScript that will call the `Opacityto()` function.

C. You probably want `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()`, because `setInterval()` will run your `Opacityto()` function every 100ms *forever*, while `setTimeout()` will run `Opacityto()` exactly once after the 100ms delay. Given that you are calling it in a loop I'm sure you don't really want to call `setInterval()` 100 times to cause your function `Opacityto()` to be run 100 times every 100ms *forever*.

D. Even fixing all of the above, your basic structure will not do what you want. When you call `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` it does not pause execution of the current block of code. So the entire for loop will run and create all of your intervals/timeouts at once, and then when the 100ms is up they'll all be triggered more or less at once. If your intention is to gradually change the opacity with each change happening every 100ms then you need the following code (or some variation thereon):

```
function fadeIn(i){
    // if called with no i parameter value initialise i
    if (typeof i === "undefined") {
       i = -1;
    }

    if (++i <= 100) {
       Opacityto(document.getElementById('nav'), i);
       setTimeout(function() { fadeIn(i); }, 100);
    }
}

// kick it off:
fadeIn();
```

What the above does is defines `fadeIn()` and then calls it passing no parameter. The function checks if `i` is undefined and if so sets it to -1 (which is what happens if you call it without passing a parameter). Then it increments `i` and checks if the result is less than or equal to 100 and if so calls `Opacityto()` passing a reference to the element and `i`. Then it uses `setTimeout()` to call *itself* in 100ms time, passing the current `i` through. Because the `setTimeout()` is inside the if test, once `i` gets big enough the function stops setting timeouts and the whole process ends.

There are several other ways you could implement this, but that's just the first that happened as I started typing...

Comment: Thank you, there's so much info in your response I need to mull over for a while. I'm still a novice coder and loop structures are enigmatic. setInteval vs. setTimeout, who knew! Probably a lot of people. Thanks for passing on the knowledge. take care

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` trip up a lot of people at first, especially when loops are involved too. Sorry about the long answer, but I think the only way I could've made it shorter would be to remove all explanation and just give my suggested new code - speaking of which, I hope my version of `fadeIn()` does the trick for you.

Comment: It did it did, thanks again (if i had the _reputation_ i would vote up your answer!)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a nasty comma inside the setInterval, messing the argument list:

```
"Opacityto("+elem,i+")"
                ^^^
                here
```

You could try quoting the comma

```
+ "," +
```

but eval is evil so don't do that. The good way is to pass a real callback function:

```
function make_opacity_setter(elem, i){
    return function(){
        OpacityTo(elem, i);
    };
}

...

setTimeout( make_opacity_setter(elem, i), 1000);
```

Do note that the intermediate function-making-function is needed to avoid the nasty interaction between closures and for-loops.

---

BTW, when you do

```
setInterval(func(), 1000)
```

you call func once yourself and then pass *its return value* to setInterval. since setInterval receives a junk value instead of a callback it won't work as you want to.